# Virus effect on flash drive filesystem (FAT)

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, virus

I've found viruses on my flash drive, but curing with antivirus didn't solved the consequences. All files and directories on the drive became links (*.lnk files) pointing to a not existing executable (it was a virus, now deleted).

I can navigate the drive with command prompt, but explorer shows me only those links:

[image: explorer and cmd]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the common virus I found nowadays on flash drives. They usually *hides (System Hidden)* all the contents of flash drive and creates shortcut for each of them pointing towards virus executable which itself is hidden.
As you have mentioned you deleted executable virus. So to see the contents simply toggle your hidden files on.
 **Note that: you need to toggle both normal hidden files and system hidden files to see those files.**
 You can find this option in `Folder and Search Option` in `Control Panel`.

[image]

*image from external source*

To mark them permanently visible uncheck their attribute `hidden` in their *Properties Window*.

To set their attributes you can also use following `attrib` command

```
I:\> attrib -H -S *.* /S /D
```

Answer (score 1):

> *How to solve this?*

1. Reformat drive and restore data from your backup copy. Or ...
2. Try to recover

   - Manually search to see if the original uncorrupted files exist elsewhere on the drive.
   - If necessary use a data recovery tool designed for use with flash drives. This may resurrect deleted files or parts of them.
   - By hand, go through and remove all the links one by one.
   - Replace the links with the original contents.

Personally I'd hit the drive with a large hammer, burn the fragments, then bury them deep in a landfill site. Then I'd spend $5 of my lunch money on a new one and make regular backups.